# How to clamp Input.mouseScrollDelta

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I am trying to make simple scrolling system using the mouse button, and clamping the camera's Y between 10 and 100, but every time, it always sends it flying, other than when I do two ifs like this:

```
            if (camera.transform.position.y < 10)
            {
                camera.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            }

            if (camera.transform.position.y > 100)
            {
                camera.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            }
```

which works, but I would like to use Clamps. Currently I just have `camera.transform.position += new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(-Input.mouseScrollDelta.y, 10, 100), 0);`

but again it sends it flying up. I have tried different combinations of this but everything ends up the same and I don't know why... Any help is apreciated

Another thing I tried that ended up doing the same thing was

```
camera.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -Input.mouseScrollDelta, 0)

Camera.transform.position += new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(camera.transform.position, 10, 100));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
camera.transform.position += Vector3.up * -Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
camera.transform.position = new Vector3(camera.transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(camera.transform.position.y, 10, 100), camera.transform.position.z);
```

or

```
Vector3 camPos = camera.transform.position;
camPos.y += -Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * speed;
camPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(camPos.y, 10, 100);
camera.transform.position = camPos;
```

Comment: It worked, but now to rest of my controls don't work, because the Vector3 is setting the x and z to 0, when I need it to just lock the Y to 10 and 100

Comment: Ok, I already updated my answer, if it helped do not forget to mark it.